# Is there an ANTLR4 Ant task?

Tags: ant, antlr4

I haven't been able find an Ant task that works out of the box with ANTLR4.  I want to be able to invoke options like -visitor to generate the *Visitor interfaces and classes.  I suppose I could 'fake it' using the Java task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need one. Take a look at the build script I use for the grammars in ANTLRWorks 2.

- Downloads the correct version of the tool on-demand (so it doesn't have to be included in source control).
- Only rebuilds grammars if they are out-of-date.
- Builds grammars in parallel for improved build times.

https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/build.xml

Comment: Pretty cool, thanks.  Downloading isn't an option in this particular project's environment (security, connectivity, etc...) but the rest will definitely help me out.  Your Ant kung fu is strong...